# Dragging rows within a tree and from another tree

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

Is it possible to create such `GtkTreeView` to be able:

- To reorder rows of that tree by DND;
- To drop rows from another tree to that tree.

GTK+ manual says about "reorderable" property:

> The reordering is implemented by setting up the tree view
>   as a drag source and destination.
>   Therefore, drag and drop can not be used in a reorderable
>   view for any other purpose.

So, I can't make my Tree reorderable with `gtk_tree_view_set_reorderable()`.
And that means that I can't implement what I want at all?

Answer (score 1):

The comment just means you can't expect GtkTreeview to do the reordering for you if you want to handle any Drag and Drop features yourself. In other words you can do what you want, but you need to set `reorderable` to FALSE and do the reordering yourself in both cases.